# How to add arrow using grid package

Tags: r, plot, r-grid

I want to add the arrow using `grid` package which will highlight the important part of my diagram. I want that the arrow will look like on the picture on the right side.

On the left part is my diagram created by the code below and on the right part is my diagram with the arrow (I've added it using Paint). It's my goal.

[image]

```
library(grid)
library(lattice)
library(sandwich)

data("Investment")
Investment <- as.data.frame(Investment)

pushViewport(plotViewport(c(5, 4, 2, 2)))
pushViewport(dataViewport(Investment$Investment, 
                      Investment$GNP,
                      name="Zaleznosc Investment od GNP"))

grid.points(Investment$Investment, Investment$GNP, gp=gpar(cex=0.5))

grid.rect()
grid.xaxis()
grid.yaxis()
grid.text("Investment", y=unit(-3, "line"))
grid.text("GNP", x=unit(-3, "line"), rot=90)
popViewport()
```

Comment: `arrow` is from grid, but working directly in grid seems like an unnecessarily difficult way to graph things now that ggplot2 exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the code that you have, but before `popViewport()` add the code to add your arrow.

```
grid.lines(x = unit(c(0.42, 0.74), "npc"),
          y = unit(c(0.8, 0.86), "npc"),
        gp = gpar(fill="black"),
          arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "inches"), 
            ends="last", type="closed"))
```

[image: Arrow]

Also,  to follow up on a comment of @alistaire grid graphics are a bit hard to use. What you are trying to do is mostly easy in base graphics.

```
plot(GNP ~ Investment, data=Investment)
arrows(250, 2600, 380, 2750, code = 2, lwd=2)
```

[image: Base Graphics]

The only thing that is not quite perfect is the type of arrowhead. The base `arrows` does not give you much control over that.  If you don't mind adding a package,  the `shape` package lets you choose the style of arrowhead.

```
library(shape)
plot(GNP ~ Investment, data=Investment)
Arrows(250, 2600, 380, 2750, code = 2, 
    arr.type="triangle", arr.width=0.4)
```

[image: With shape]

Answer (score 1):

[In his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218643/how-to-add-arrow-using-grid-package#comment83419390_48218643), @alistaire has mentioned `ggplot2` as an alternative to working with `grid` directly.

For the sake of completeness, here is a `ggplot2` version which uses the `annotate()` function to place an arrow on the chart.

```
data(Investment, package = "sandwich")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(as.data.frame(Investment)) +
  aes(Investment, GNP) +
  geom_point(shape = 1L) +
  theme_bw() +
  annotate("segment", x = 250, xend = 380, y = 2600, yend = 2800, 
           arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "inches"), ends = "last", type = "closed"))
```

[image]

Note that `ggplot2` reexports the `arrow()` function from the `grid` package.